# Django change the default path for login form

Tags: django, django-templates

In Django by default, the path for login is **registration/login.html**.
Problem is that I want to use the login form inside the main index page not in another page.

For this login page, there is no function in views.py and no path or url in URLS.py

If I put the below codes in **webpage/registration/login.html**, the login form works. But if I put the codes in **webpage/index.html** the login is not successful.

```
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
```

How is it possible to change the default login path to look on **webpage/index.html** and not on **registration/login.html**?

Update:
I put the below codes as suggested here. It changed the login url to the index.html address. But still login is not working there.

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class WebpageLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'webpage/index.html'
```

Comment: your question a little ambigious. do you mean you want your login page to be like a popup form on the index page?

Comment: @Chymdy I updated the information. Popup is an option. But it is also a part of another page, so the method would be the same I think. (If you can use it as a popup you can also use it as a part of a page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use LoginView from `django.contrib.auth` module, you can make use of python inheritance and change the default template name from `registration/login.html` to `webpage/index.html` as follows:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class WebpageLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'webpage/index.html'
```

However, this is not a good approach if the contents of `webpage/index.html` is not static and some other data has to be processed by the form to render a response. In this case, you can override `get_context_data` method of `LoginView` and put your logic there, but this is not a good practice.

Comment: I added your code to the views.py but it still does not work. Login is still possible through the registration/login.html.

Comment: Have you tried to add or update the path to `WebpageLoginView` in your `urls.py`. If not, try it. Also, could you please edit your question to provide contents of your `urls.py` and `views.py` (maybe only the view that serves your `webpage/index.html` for now), so we could better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make use of your request function since you use CBVs.

something like:

```
from django.contrib,view import generic # confirm that this import is correct.

class WebpageLoginView(generic.View):
    template_name = 'webpage/index.html
    
        def post(request):
            # make your authentication here
```

As long as your page loads using the get method, whenever a form on the page makes a post request, it will be treated as an attempt to login.